# WebPack optimization with Awesome-Typescript-Loader not seeing much improvement

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to improve my WebPack performance so I switched out `TS-Loader` for `Awesome-TypeScript-Loader`, and my compile times only increased a tiny bit. I had heard `ATL` is supposed to be much faster, but I only shaved off maybe a few 100ms.

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

const webpack               = require('webpack');
const path                  = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin     = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin    = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
const CleanWebpackPlugin    = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const StyleLintPlugin       = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const { CheckerPlugin, TsConfigPathsPlugin }     = require('awesome-typescript-loader')

// const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

// borrowed from the ng2 seed
const entryPoints = ['inline', 'polyfills', 'sw-register', 'styles', 'vendor', 'app'];

const htmlConfig = {
  template: 'client/_index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  // borrowed from the ng2 seed
  chunksSortMode: (left, right) => {
    const leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
    const rightIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
    if (leftIndex > rightIndex) {
      return 1;
    } else if (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
};

function isExternal(module) {
  const match = typeof module.userRequest === 'string' &&
    /node_modules/.test(module.userRequest.split('!').pop());
  return match;
}

// const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name].[hash].css', allChunks: true })
// const extractJS = new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name].[hash].js', allChunks: true })

module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  entry: {
    polyfills: './client/app/polyfills.js',
    // base: './client/base.js',
    app: './client/app/app.ts'
  },
  output: {
    // Absolute output directory
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),

    // Output path from the view of the page
    // Uses webpack-dev-server in development
    publicPath: '/',

    // Filename for entry points
    // Only adds hash in build mode
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',

    // Filename for non-entry points
    // Only adds hash in build mode
    chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      'vue-router$': 'vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js',
      'vuex$': 'vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js',
      'vuex-class$': 'vuex-class/dist/vuex-class.cjs.js',
      'styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/app/styles'),
      'core': path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/app/core'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/app/components'),
      'containers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/app/containers'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/assets'),
      'config': path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/config')
    }
  },
  // Use 'source-map' for more accurate source mapping
  // Use 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' for faster rebuilding
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // ES LINT LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader
        // Lint ECMAScript
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'eslint-loader', options: { cache: true } }
        ],
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')]
      },
      {
        // TS LINT LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
        // Lint TypeScript
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['tslint-loader'],
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')]
      },
      {
        // SOURCE MAP LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader
        // Extracts SourceMaps for source files that as added as sourceMappingURL comment
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(j|t|s?(a|c)s)s$/, // ts or js or css or scss or sass (or ass)
        use: ['source-map-loader'],
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/css-loader/lib/convert-source-map.js')] // There is a sourceMappingURL example in this file that triggers a warning
      },
      {
        // JS LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader
        // Transpile .js files using babel-loader
        // Compiles ES6 and ES7 into ES5 code
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, cacheDirectory: true } }
        ],
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
      },
      {
        // AWESOME TYPESCRIPT LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
        // Transpile .ts files using awesome-typescript-loader
        // Compiles TS into ES6 code
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          // { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, cacheDirectory: true } },
          // { loader: 'ts-loader' }
          { loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, useCache: true, useBabel: true, useTranspileModule: true } }
        ],
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
      },
      {
        // ASSET LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/url-loader
        // Copy png, jpg, jpeg, gif, svg, woff, woff2, ttf, eot files to output
        // Rename the file using the asset hash
        // Pass along the updated reference to your code
        // You can add here any file extension you want to get copied to your output
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|mp4)([?]?.*)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: 'assets/[name].[hash].[ext]' } }
        ]
      },
      {
        // HTML LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/html-loader
        // Allow loading html through js
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              exportAsEs6Default: true,
              root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
              // Look for and process the following tag:attr on html elements
              attrs: [
                'img:src',
                'video:src'
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        // CSS LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, importLoaders: 1 } },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
        ]
      },
      {
        // SASS LOADER
        // Reference: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, importLoaders: 2 } },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      cache: true,
      debug: true,
      minimize: false
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
    new TsConfigPathsPlugin(),
    new CheckerPlugin(),
    new StyleLintPlugin({
      files: ['./client/**/*.s?(a|c)ss']
    }),
    // Remove dist and build directories before building
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    // extractCSS,
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      // Only analyze the app entry point, we don't want to change the others
      chunks: ['app'],
      // Check if module is in node_modules
      minChunks: (module) => {
        return isExternal(module);
      }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(htmlConfig)
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: false,
    inline: true,
    hot: true
  }
};
```

And my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ES2017",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ScriptHost"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "styles/*": ["./client/app/styles/*"],
      "core/*": ["./client/app/core/*"],
      "components/*": ["./client/app/components/*"],
      "containers/*": ["./client/app/containers/*"],
      "assets/*": ["./client/assets/*"],
      "config/*": ["./client/config/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And the .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env", {
      "modules": false,
      "useBuiltIns": true,
      "debug": true,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [
          "last 1 Chrome version"
        ]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

I'm targeting ES2017 from TS and leaving it up to Babel to compile for our target browser; as in development we want the extra performance of native code, and less difference of the transpiled coutput.

It seems to be hung up on Babel, especially, as it gets bogged down in the "asset optimization" stage.
`TS-loader + Babel`: ~1500ms
`ATL + Babel`: ~1100ms
`ATL - Babel`: ~800ms

Also, I don't see any performance difference with ATL between `useCache: true/false` nor `useTranspileModule: true/false`. But I do see it making a TON of files in the .awcache folder, every time it recompiles (wondering if something is cache busting).

Running webpack-dev-server with params:
`webpack-dev-server --watch --hot --progress --open`

Using the latest versions of all packages, loaders, and tools as of this post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Should it be `useCache: true` in the options of the awesome-typescript-loader instead of `cacheDirectory: true`. This seemingly would set the directory you are to be using for caching to the value `true`